# Scale/Resize a single letter in mathmode with its subscript/superscript unchanged

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, scaling

Is there a way to do this? Currently I am using something like the following to do the job on scaling of a single letter in an equation:

```
\[
\int_{\Omega} (u - \text{\Large $\Pi_{\Omega}$} u) v \, dx = 0
\]
```

or

```
\[
\int_{\Omega} (u - \text{\scalebox{1.5}{$\Pi_{\Omega}$}} u) v \, dx = 0
\]
```

and as you can see, the `\Omega` in the subscript of `\Pi` is obviously bigger than the `\Omega` as the domain of the integral sign:
[image: the comparison of Omega]

I am curious if there is a way to manually adjust the size of the sub/sup-script of this resized letter? I tried using `\scriptsize` and `\scriptstyle`, both seem not working in `mathmode`? or is there another solution for the rescaling/resizing other than exploiting `\text{}` or `\scalebox{}[]{}`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're probably looking for `\prod\nolimits_{\Omega}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "large Pi" symbol you're looking for is called `\prod` (the analog of `\sum` for products)

```
\[
\int_{\Omega} (u - \prod\nolimits_{\Omega} u) v \, dx = 0
\]
```

The `\nolimits` is to avoid the subscript to go below the symbol in display style.

[image]

If you need a smaller symbol in display style, you can define

```
\newcommand{\sprod}{\mathop{\mathchoice
  {\textstyle\prod}
  {\prod}
  {\prod}
  {\prod}
}\nolimits}
```

and the result of

```
\[
\int_{\Omega} (u - \sprod_{\Omega} u) v \, dx = 0
\]
```

would be as follows

[image]